# Distributed network-quality monitoring for Windows

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

My office is cursed with a very unreliable network. From time to time things just seem to stop working - the servers are all fine. We think the fault lies in the wires and routers between our computers.

My team looks after a large number of Windows servers and workstations. Each PC runs a number of distributed applications, hence any computer could potentially need to talk to any other computer.

The servers all run a monitoring application that allows us to guarantee the health of the PC and all the processes that run on it, but we do not have anything that will let us judge the health of the network that connects all our servers together.

Is there some application that would allow us to monitor the health of the network? Preferably this would be distributed amongst our machines so that we can look at the network from more than one perspective.

I'd like to be able to do basic stuff like pings but also higher-level stuff such as sending simulated transactions from one machine to one of our servers.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solarwinds is the best one I have seen out there. It will do all of the things you are asking but it does come at a pretty big price tag once you get all the network components on there.

http://www.solarwinds.com

Answer (score 0):

use [ntop](http://www.ntop.org). You can see the whole network activity. who is uploading and downloading. which ports are open.